# Is okay to copy a paste from js/css libraries?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working with jQuery and or bootstrap type libraries for a while and find that I often use them for only a few purposes and or functions().

Is it okay to copy out on the parts that I need into one file? Can you give credit at the top of the file? Is this breaking any copyrights and or legal boundaries?

Just wondering,

Matt

Comment: It is more of a maintainability issue.

Comment: This will depend on the licence of each library.

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that question matches StackOverflow rules because it is more an opinion matter than a problem with single solution or, at least, where one solution can be better than other.

But I think it is an interesting question.

I also wondered it by myself many times and my conclusion is that I fully agree @str comment: «It is more of a maintainability issue».

But, if you deicide to rely on your own mix, there are also some caveats to take in mind:

1. Except for simple (and short) functions and only if you read and analyze it before, you cannot be sure that they won't fail unexpectedly in because of the lack of other function or object it uses only in infrequent cases.
2. Most of those libraries are also available in minified version, so its impact on bandwidth use or loading delay may be not too much in most cases. And, specially, if you doesn't minify your compilation, you may end up having the same or even higher cost.
3. Most browsers support http compression and caches requests so, again, the benefit of saving a few functions may be not so much...
4. Internet connections nowadays are pretty fast and, usually, there is more overhead in connection establishment and http headers than in actual content transmission so, maybe, your effort would be better invested in concatenating all those javascript files in single minified one to reduce all those latencies. The advantage of that is that is easier to rebuild when you want to update any of the libraries. And, of course, you can easily automate it if you want.

Comment: Seems your suggestions it not worth the effort, because can minify and use gulp/grunt to append to same file. a combination of that and caching is a more sustainable solution, yes. thanks for your response!